# Apache Server is not running from XAMPP Control Panel. Giving Error

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed XAMPP (xampp-win32-1.8.2-0-VC9-installer.exe) on Windows 7 successfully. But unfortunately, the following error was found during running Apache from XAMPP Control Panel:

```
PM 05:36:44  [Apache]   Apache Service detected with wrong path
PM 05:36:44  [Apache]   Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
PM 05:36:44  [Apache]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
PM 05:36:44  [Apache]   Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
PM 05:36:44  [Apache]   Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

Comment: Have you installed another Apache server before? Seems that way ...

Comment: Yes, I have installed the previous version once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problems as stated above, made sure nothing was using port 80 and still not working and getting the message that Apache and Mysql were detected with wrong path.

I did install XAMPP once before, uninstalled and reinstalled. I even manually uninstalled but still had issues.

The fix. Make sure you backup your system first!!!

```
Start Services via Control Panel>Admin Tools

Look for Apache and mySQL services. Look at the patch indicated in the description (right click on service then click on properties). Chances are that you have Apache listed twice, one from your correct install and one from a previous install. Even if you only see one, look at the path, chances are its from a previous install and causing your install not to work. In either case, you need to delete those incorrect services.

a. Got to command prompt (run as administrator): Start > all programs > Accessories > right click on Command Prompt > Select 'run as administrator'

b. on command prompt type sc delete service (service = the service you're wanting to delete) such as apache2.1. It should be exactly as it appears in your services. If the service has spaces such as apache 2.1 then enter it in quotes, i.e. sc delete "apache 2.1"

c. press enter. Now refresh or close/open your services window and you'll see its gone.
```

DO THIS for all services that XAMPP finds as running with incorrect path.

Once you do this, go head and restart the XAMPP control panel (as administrator) and that's . No conflicts